# SASS function/mixins for property value

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Here's an example mixin:

```
=border($alpha: 0.2)
    1px solid hsla(0, 0, 0, $alpha)
```

I want to use functions/mixins to achieve something like this:

`border-right: +border(0.2)`

This will compile into:

`border-right: 1px solid hsla(0, 0, 0, 0.2)`

I have not seen any documentation on how to use functions/mixins to dynamically calculate property values. I have only seen them used when they include the property as well. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Docs: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions

Comment: Example: http://pastie.org/1230161

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can write functions like this:

```
@function border($alpha: 0.2)
  $border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0, 0, $alpha)
  @return $border
```

and apply them like any other sass/compass function:

```
border-right: border(0.2)
```

Comment: Just a reference to the official doc: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#function_directives